# Parse.com How to process 5 000 000 rows with a Cloud Job?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I've got 5M chats in my data base, each of the chats might have from 2 to 1000 users, so I decided to switch them to Many-to-Many relationships.

The "Chats" table has a column "connected" (Bool). If connected is true, it means that the Chat is switched to new structure and we don`t need to process it anymore. But the problem is that, when I use Cloud.job, I can process only first 500k chats. Then suddenly queries return 0 results as there were no chats at all. This is how the Cloud Job query looks like:

```
var query = new Parse.Query("Chats");
query.doesNotExist("connected");
query.descending("createdAt");
query.limit(1000);
query.find().then(function(dialogues) { 
   //...the code to process Chats... 
});
```

So. Each minute it must get 1000 chats which are NOT connected. I started the job two days ago. In 8 hours it stopped returning any results. It just says, that this query returns 0 chats.

Comment: You checked that you have not hit the request limit on Parse ?? (1800 requests over a 60 second) Check the performance graph in Analytics page

Comment: Sure. I`ve got a limit of 235 req/s. 1800 per 60 sec is 30 per sec only.